# SQL query to select distinct from data table along with the corresponding column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a data table that contains 4 fields `[UpdatedDate]`, `[DoggoName]`, `[DoggoType]` and `[DoggoAge]`.

`[DoggoName]` will always have the same `[DoggoType]` and `[DoggoAge]` values.

```
UpdatedDate DoggoName   DoggoType        DoggoAge
1-Jan       a           Labrador         1
1-Jan       b           Yorkshire        2
1-Jan       c           German Shepherd  3
1-Jan       e           Bull Terrier     2
2-Jan       a           Labrador         1
2-Jan       d           Golden Retriever 1
2-Jan       e           Bull Terrier     2
2-Jan       f           Poodle           3
3-Jan       a           Labrador         1
3-Jan       b           Yorkshire        2
3-Jan       c           German Shepherd  3
```

I am looking to select the distinct `[DoggoName]` between 2 `[UpdatedDate]` and their corresponding `[DoggoType]` and '[DoggoAge]`.

So far I only managed to come up with a basic SQL query to draw out distinct `[DoggoName]`. Print on Excel then loop through the rows of `[DoggoName]` to draw out the 2 other columns. I was wondering if there's a single query that skips my tedious loops.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [DoggoName] 
FROM [DataTable] 
WHERE [UpdatedDate] BETWEEN #1-Jan-2018# AND #2-Jan-2018#
```

My final output should look like this:

```
DoggoName   DoggoType        DoggoAge
a           Labrador         1
b           Yorkshire        2
c           German Shepherd  3
e           Bull Terrier     2
d           Golden Retriever 1
f           Poodle           3
```

Comment: use group by ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` to `select` your expection columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DoggoName,DoggoName,DoggoAge
FROM DataTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am sure you can use the following Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Doggoname], Doggotype, Doggo_age 
from datatable where [UpdatedDate] BETWEEN #1-Jan-2018# AND #2-Jan-2018#
```

Also, you can use the following as there is a single record available for each Doggotype

```
Select distinct doggoname , max(doggotype) as doggotype, max(age) as age from 
datatable
where updateddate between #1-Jan-2018# AND #2-Jan-2018#
group by 1;
quit;
```